# How do I find cost and delay for parallel A* algorithm

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, big-o, path-finding

For the sequential method I found that the total number of elements to calculate was O(|E|+|V|log|V|), the cost was simply O(1) since there was only one processor being used and the delay was O(ElogV).

When I look into Parallel A* and Parallel New Bidirectional A*, I am struggling to figure out how to figure this out. I feel the cost for the bidirectional A* should be O(2) since I am simple running the start and end point at the same time to find where the two points meet, but I don't know if that's right at all and I don't even know where to begin with figuring out the delay for multiple processors. Can someone please help?

Comment: Writing O(2) suggest that you're not yet familiar with big-O notation. Analyzing Parallelism and complex algorithms like A* (even sequential) might be a slight overreach for you at this point. I suggest you first investigate the difference between O(1) and O(2).

Comment: O(2) is the same as O(1). That's my point. We want to help, and sometimes the best way to do that is to point to the textbook.